# OCaml dynamic linking and -nodynlink compilation flag

Tags: ocaml, dynamic-linking

According to the [OCaml User's Manual chapter on `ocamlopt`](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/native.html):

> `-nodynlink` Allow the compiler to use some optimizations that are valid only for code that is never dynlinked.
> ...
> **`-shared`** [...] Under some systems (currently, only Linux AMD 64), all the OCaml code linked in a plugin must have been compiled without the `-nodynlink` flag. [...]

To me, this implies that:

- The restriction "do not use the `-nodynlink` compilation flag" *only* applies to the plugin.
- Non-plugin parts (the application being extended) may be compiled using `-nodynlink`.

So my actual question is two-fold:

1. Is my above interpretation correct?
2. When I violated above restrictions on purpose, the compiler/loader/etc did not give me a warning message. What kind of errors / bad behavior would I have to expect as a result of my wrongdoing?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first point is correct. However many modern operating systems use PIE executables by default, which is incompatible with the `-nodynlink` option.

Concerning your second point, specifying the `-shared` in second position will erase the `-nodynlink` flag, which may explain why you did not get any error. Otherwise, for non-empty plugins, the linker should generate a relocation error. Typically trying to compile

```ml
let printer () = Format.printf "I am a plugin@."
let () = Lib.register := printer :: !Lib.register
```

with

```
# ocamlopt -shared -nodynlink plugin.ml -o plugin.cmxs
```

gives me

> ```
> /usr/bin/ld: plugin.o: warning: relocation against `camlPlugin__Pfield_51' in >read-only section `.text'
> /usr/bin/ld: plugin.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol >`camlPlugin__const_block_11' can not be used when making a shared object; >recompile with -fPIC
> /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
> ```